# Vuetify apply rules validation to a custom component

Tags: javascript, validation, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'd like to use [Vuetify custom validation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields#custom-validation) on a custom component.

E.g I created a date time picker component

**DateTimePicker.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-menu v-model="menu" :close-on-content-click="false" full-width max-width="290" transition="scale-transition">
    <!-- Text field -->
    <v-text-field slot="activator" :label="label" append-icon="date_range" solo
                  :value="formattedDate" readonly></v-text-field>

    <!-- Date picker -->
    <v-date-picker v-model="selectedDate" locale="fr-fr" v-if="datePicker" :min="minDate">
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-btn flat color="primary" @click="menu = false">{{ $t('cancel') }}</v-btn>
      <v-btn flat color="primary" @click="chooseDate">{{ $t('ok') }}</v-btn>
    </v-date-picker>

    <!-- Time picker -->
    <v-time-picker v-if="!datePicker" v-model="selectedTime" format="24hr" :min="minTime" :allowed-minutes="allowedStep">
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-btn flat color="primary" @click="menu = false">{{ $t('cancel') }}</v-btn>
      <v-btn flat color="primary" @click="chooseTime">{{ $t('ok') }}</v-btn>
    </v-time-picker>
  </v-menu>
</template>
```

And I want to apply rules validation on my custom component in my parent component.

**Parent.vue**

```
   <v-container fluid grid-list-xl>
      <v-layout row wrap class="pt-4">
        <v-flex xs12 md3>
          <v-autocomplete ref="city" v-model="city" :items="locations" item-text="description" :label="$t('stores')" solo
                          :rules="[rules.required]"></v-autocomplete>
        </v-flex>

        <!-- Start date picker -->
        <v-flex xs12 md3>
          <date-time-picker ref="startDate" v-model="startDate" :label="$t('start_date')" :rules="[rules.required]"></date-time-picker>
        </v-flex>

        <!-- End date picker -->
        <v-flex xs12 md3>
          <date-time-picker v-model="endDate" :label="$t('end_date')"></date-time-picker>
        </v-flex>

        <v-flex xs12 md3>
          <v-btn class="primary btn-bigger" @click="valdiate" block> {{ $t('search') }}</v-btn>
        </v-flex>

      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
```

I'd like to do the same thing as I did for my `v-autocomplete`. I tried to use rules props on my `<date-time-picker>` and use it on my `<v-text-field>` inside my custom component but it doesn't work I got this error :

`_this2.$refs[f].validate is not a function`

I took the same code as the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields#custom-validation) so it works for my `<v-autocomplete>` but I don't know how can I do for my custom component.

Answer (score 5):

You need to send from your parent component to your child (DateTimePicker) the array of rules as props and then bind this in your v-text-field component (inside your child component: DateTimePicker).

#### For example

1. Add to your component (*DateTimePicker*) a property **"rules"**. Eg

```
    props: { 
        rules: {
            type: Array,
            required: false
        }
    }
```

2. And then bind rules (**:rules="rules"**) in your *v-text-field* component. Eg

```
    <v-text-field slot="activator" :label="label" append-icon="date_range" solo
                  :value="formattedDate" readonly
                  :rules="rules">
    </v-text-field>
```

3. Then, bind **rules** to your child component in your parent. You don't need any change because you have done it with **:rules="[rules.required]"**. Eg

```
        <v-flex xs12 md3>
          <date-time-picker ref="startDate" v-model="startDate" :label="$t('start_date')"
                    :rules="[rules.required]">
          </date-time-picker>
        </v-flex>
```

Comment: And for v-form valid

Comment: this doesn't quite work, if you are trying to keep the v-model a date object right? the v-text-field would be set to a string representation, and the rules would be given a string result from the text-field